# Como puedo mostrar 20 items por pagina en un listview?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo un listview que cargo desde firebase realtime database, y quisiera añadirle pagination con 2 botones debajo que muestren pagina anterior, siguiente y en el medio muestro el numero de pagina donde se encuentra, pero no se como implementarlo en mi listview, he probado con añadir getItemCount en mi adapter pero no se mas debo añadir.

```
 MessagesAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Message> objects, ChatActivity chatActivity) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.ctx = context;
    this.messageObjects = (ArrayList<Message>) objects;
    this.dataUpdateAfterMessageDelete = chatActivity;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


}


ublic void getThreads() {
    mDatabase.child("Normas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            threadsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot messageThreadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessageThread messageThread = messageThreadSnapshot.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                if (messageThread != null) {
                    messageThread.thread_id = messageThreadSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + messageThread.toString());
                }
                threadsList.add(messageThread);
            }
            threadsAdapter = new ThreadsAdapter(ThreadsActivity.this, R.layout.threads_listview, threadsList, ThreadsActivity.this);
            threadsListView.setAdapter(threadsAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

En Android, no hace falta poner las guias y el numero de página ya que no va con la experiencia de usuario, en cambio, deberias hacer scroll de 20 elementos y luego ir cargando de a 20 mientras vas bajando.

Una buena soluciona a esto es la libreria de [Paging 3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) que está hecha para este proposito. Otra forma seria que haces un fetch con un limit de 20 elementos y luego almacenas la key del ultimo elemento, al llegar al ultimo elemento del recyclerivew chequeas mediante un metodo de recylcerview si el ultimo elemento es igual a la ultima key que buscaste, si es asi, cargas de nuevo 20 elementos pero ahora comenzando desde la posicion 20 + 20 , seria, empezar desde la posicion 40 y cargar 20 elementos, esto lo puedes lograr con limit en la consulta.

Luego de traer los datos deberias usar addAll para agregarlo a la lista